# Java appending an element to XML document

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodes

I am trying to append an element to my xml document so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<students>
</students>
```

However, it ends up looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<students/>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
// results is the new XML document I created using DocumentBuilder.newDocument();
Element root = results.createElement("students");
results.appendChild(root);
```

How come it isn't looking like how I want it to?

Comment: <students></students> and <students /> are equivalent. It is an XML shorthand when the element has no children. Once you append more children into the root, it should automatically expand.

Comment: @Xen Thanks, did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java dom is implemented based on the xml specification, and by definition: An element with no content is said to be empty : https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags.